# Unable to create type 'Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net'

Tags: c#, wcf, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have WCF project with other class libraries in a solution. I added Common.Logging using nuget package manager for projects which require logging.

I am getting this error  :

> Unable to create type
>   'Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter,
>   Common.Logging.Log4Net'

when I excute :

```
Common.Logging.ILog logger = Common.Logging.LogManager.GetLogger<Service1>();
logger.Error("Test");
```

My Web.Config is [here](https://gist.github.com/divsoft/169ebb487420ff1290ce)

EDIT :
Bin Folder have Common.Logging.Log4net1213.dll as well as log4net.dll
[image: Snapshot of Bin Folder content related to Common.Logging]

Comment: It is likely that either `log4net` is not referenced in your assemblies **or** you need to use the fully qualified namespace here: `type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: I think assembly should be resolved from web.config code (added by nuget) `<runtime>

    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

      <dependentAssembly>

        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />

        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.11.0" newVersion="1.2.11.0" />

      </dependentAssembly>

    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>`

Comment: Unfortunately that's not necessarily true, I actually have this problem regularly on one of the projects I work on.

Comment: Any inner exception?

Comment: @MatteoSp : yes there is : `{"Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Logging.Log4Net' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Common.Logging.Log4Net"}`

Answer (score 9):

Check if your Common.Logging.Log4net.dll is copied to your output directory. In most cases the dll is missing because there is no direct reference in the project.

In your config you have:

```
<logging>

  <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net">

    <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />

  </factoryAdapter>

</logging>
```

Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net -> references the Common.Logging.Log4Net.dll which is not in your directory. There is a Common.Logging.Log4Net1213.dll dll. So you can change the config to:

```
<logging>

  <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net1213">

    <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />

  </factoryAdapter>

</logging>
```

Or rename the dll

Comment: since nuget package manager is used to handle the packages, it better to update the config to reflect the correct DLL name, instead of second option of renaming the DLL