# Adding log4net to a legacy webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services, wcf

**Background**

I'm updating a legacy webservice application, one of the necessary steps is to have it use log4net.

**What I want to do**

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when the application is started
    Dim log As ILog = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
    log.Trace("Start Application")
End Sub
```

**Result**

This error:

> An exception of type 'Common.Logging.ConfigurationException' occurred
>   in Common.Logging.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to create type
>   'Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter,
>   Common.Logging.Log4Net'

**Symptoms**

Doing the above works just fine in a WCF application I have (which has a global.asax because of external complexities).

I checked the web.config, it's identical to that of the WCF application.

Upgrading the webservice (to a WCF) is not an option.

**Question**

Is it possible to use log4net in a webservice context?

Comment: have you tried to configure your log4net by code and not by configfile?

Comment: Not really an option. I can't decide to configure it differently (nor do I have the time). It would break the consistency of the way all applications are handled.

Comment: differently to what?

Comment: and may have a look to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595476/unable-to-create-type-common-logging-log4net-log4netloggerfactoryadapter-commo

Comment: All other applications. I would break the coding guidelines and the way things are installed.

Comment: @harmoniemand: Regarding the link, I saw that. Didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the cause was a mismatch between the Log4Net references:

```
Common.Logging
Common.Logging.Core
Common.Logging.log4net1211
log4net
```

Now the first three are all 2.2.0.0 and the last reference is 1.2.13.0.